# Making generic interface in java through generics

Tags: java, generics

I am using the below interface as shown below

```
public interface ZaestrorardRule {

    Map<String, List<MMTM>> exceute(String jobCode, String Plientlo) throws AaestroRardNetworkException;

}
```

and then there is a class which implement it as shown below

```
public class AaestroRardBusinessRNFRuleImpl implements ZaestrorardRule {

    public Map<String, List<MMTM>> exceute(String jobCode, String Plientlo) throws AaestroRardNetworkException {

    }

}
```

Now lets say I am working on some other functionality apart from ZaestrorardRule shown above, which has the same functionality like ZaestrorardRule then I have to create a separate interface as shown below

```
public interface WWaestrorardRule {

    Map<String, List<MMTM>> exceute(String jobCode, String Plientlo) throws AaestroRardNetworkException;

}
```

My query is that can I use generic in interface so that there will be a single interface as the structure of the interface is fixed.

Comment: The two interfaces in your question are identical, so why do you need two of them?

Comment: @Eran Well i want to use only one ,but that is also of generic one

Comment: Does anything need to be different between the two interfaces, like the return type or the parameters of `execute` method?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele Well rite now it is fixed as shown above and also the parameter input parameter also

Comment: @wdwddsd Then you already have it. All you need is different implementations of the same, single interface, which has already defined the required method. Perhaps the only change required is a more generic name for `ZaestrorardRule`

Comment: ***...I am working on some other functionality apart from ZaestrorardRule shown above, which has the same functionality like ZaestrorardRule...*** how there can be another functionality which has the same functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As concluded in the question comments, you don't actually need to make a generic interface since both your interfaces have the same parameter and return types. Instead, what you'd do is something like:

```
public interface Rule {

    Map<String, List<MMTM>> execute(String s1, String s2) throws YourException;

}
```

And then you have different *implementations* of `Rule`:

```
public class ZaestrorardRule implements Rule {
    // implement interface
}

public class WWaestrorardRule implements Rule {
    // implement interface
}
```

This is how an interface is supposed to be used.

---

If you were to need different parameter types or return type then you would start using generics. Already your interface resembles a `java.util.function.BiFunction` except that it throws a custom exception (which is most likely a checked exception). Simply do what `BiFunction` does:

```
public interface Rule<T, U, R> {
    R execute(T t, U u) throws YourException;
}
```

You could also simply this if both parameters will always be the same type by declaring the interface as `Rule<T, R>` and the method as `R execute(T t1, T t2) throws YourException`.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, we can extend interfaces. You can create a parent interface:

```
public interface GenericRule {

    Map<String, List<MMTM>> exceute(String jobCode, String Plientlo) throws AaestroRardNetworkException;

}
```

Change your both interfaces like this

```
public interface ZaestrorardRule extends GenericRule {

}

public interface WWaestrorardRule extends GenericRule {

}
```

Comment: While that solution is technically correct, it does not provide any additional value. Why would you want to create multiple interfaces that do absolutely the same?

Comment: @lu.koerfer Agree with you completely, I am looking to introduce generics into it

Comment: Both interface ZaestrorardRule  and WWaestrorardRule  may have different implementations later though.

Comment: @ArnabDhar You do not need (and not even want) multiple interfaces for multiple implementations. That is in fact the idea of an interface. Creating multiple interfaces just for multiple implementations is a design mistake.